# Is their a way to synchronise a directory on a raspberry pi to a laptop using WinSCP

Tags: ftp, raspberry-pi, winscp

I want to be able to synchronize a directory between my Windows laptop and raspberry pi using WinSCP. By "synchronize" I mean if a file is created in the directory by my raspberry pi, it is automatically placed in predefined directory on my laptop.

I have already set up a WinSCP connection between these two devices.

I was following along using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndvEYOQLc4c however I reliazed that this was for an FTP server and I also could not save the .bat file or code file into the appropriate directory as it has it has an administrator lock, so I assume that the method is only for FTB servers.

**Edit**

I have given myself permissions to save the code files in the appropriate places, however I now receive the error

```
Host "lynn-vs2.cloudapp.net" does not exist.
```

Whenever I run the **bat** file:

```
winscp.com /script=SyncToLocalScript.txt
```

pause

Which in turn runs the **txt** file:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://sftpuser04:password123!@lynn-vs2.cloudapp.net -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 256 00:69:55:c8:a8:84:01:6d:7c:ff:9f:8c:89:b3:7d:67"
synchronize local C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Desktop\RaspPCAP /home/pi/Desktop/PCapFiles
exit
```

I am not sure what "lynn-vs2.cloudapp.net" is.

Comment: Just save the bat/code to any directory, where you have permissions for.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just saved them in the correct place by giving myself administrator privileges

Comment: Saving the file to a location that requires administrator privileges is probably *not the correct place*. But as you wish.

Comment: Regarding your new problem: Can you connect to `lynn-vs2.cloudapp.net` anyhow? Using WinSCP GUI? Using any other SFTP/SSH client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No i could not connect to it. Is their any alternative?

Comment: Alternative to what? Afaik, Raspberry Pi, as most Linux servers, does run SFTP/SSH server by default. So what you do, should work, assuming your hostname is correct. If it does not work, you do not have a programming question, so it does not belong here. For connectivity problems, go to [su], or more specifically to [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Rather than synchronise files and copy them backwards and forwards, you could just share a directory on your PC with the Pi, or on your Pi with the PC like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761844/2836621