# Creating RESTful server for raspbery pi 4 to display images

Tags: api, rest, raspberry-pi, flask-restful, raspberry-pi4

I got a task and have absolutely no clue on how to do it at the moment.

I watched a couple of tutorials on REST API, but none of them are applicable for my application. I don't intend to use a localhost, but if it's required then sure.

What is this task?

So there are two parts.

1. PC (client)
2. Raspberry Pi 4 (server)

Here’s the sequence:

The PC is the client and sends a request to the server, which is the Raspberry Pi 4, to display an image, let's say `image1.jpg`. The rpi4 is connected to an external monitor via HDMI.

The server/Raspberry Pi 4 receives the request and opens up `image1.jpg` which will then be displayed on the screen in full screen to be shown on the screen through HDMI.

Perhaps there is a better solution than to use RESTful API to solve this. If there is please give me recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts to this:

- capturing an image
- displaying an image
- telling RasPi to do both the above

---

In order to capture an image you can use `raspistill` or [libcamera](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html) utils in newer versions of Raspberry Pi OS.

If you aren't capturing pictures with the camera, you must presumably be supplying them from the PC. So you can either use `scp` to copy one across from the PC:

```
scp SOMEIMAGE.JPG raspberrypi:image.jpg
```

Or you can use a Windows SHARE to share a directory between the PC and the RasPi. In Windows you'd use the "Share Folder" option and on the RasPi you can use `smbclient` or `cifs-utils` to mount it. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761844/2836621).

---

In order to display an image, either use `raspistill` built-in options, or use `fbi` or `fim` or `feh` depending on how things are connected and whether you are running an X11 server or not.

---

In order to tell RasPi to do the above, just use `ssh` (or Putty on Windows) like this:

```
ssh user@raspberrypi 'raspistill ... -o /tmp/image.jpg; fim /tmp/image.jpg'
```

Note that RasPi implements `avahi`, so if your Raspberry Pi's hostname is set to `simon`, you should be able to talk to it under the name `simon.local` on your network, so the command above would become:

```
ssh user@simon.local '...'
```

where `user` is your username that you login to your RasPi with.

You can set your RasPi hostname with:

```
sudo raspi-config
```